# Large File I/O Async vs. Multi-Threaded Sync I/O

Tags: c++, linux, multithreading

I've got a Linux program which is copying fairly large files(400MB to 10GB) to a remote NFS server.  I am currently using synchronous I/O calls to copy the data to the NFS mount.  All of these calls are occurring within separate threads in a thread pool.  So I'm not really blocking the operation of the main thread.

I've heard a lot about using Linux AIO for tasks like these.  But I don't really see the advantage it would give for large files.

What are some of the pros/cons of using AIO versus running synchronous IO in threads?  Are there any statistical comparisons of this type of scenario out there in the web?

Comment: Glibc AIO is the same as what you are doing. Kernel AIO will not work for NFS.

Answer (score 1):

To faster data transfer, you may want to transfer file chunks in parallel. This requires many parallel threads. With AIO, you can initiate multiple data transfers with limited number of threads, so saving memory for thread stacks. But if the number of parallel data transfers that network and NFS server can process is limited, better use threads for simplicity of programming.